# embedded pdf inside original pdf

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to embed or show a pdf inside a main pdf. Suppose user click on "Address" - is there a way to popup another pdf showing the detailed address from which the user can copy.

Comment: You can create a pdf portfolio with the `embedfile` package and create a link to the embedded pdfs with the `hypgotoe` package.